# Is it possible to send a value/ng-model from one directive template to another? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, directive

Let's think of the most simple example here.

How do I send the value of a text input from the template of directive A as a filter for a list that exists as ng-repeat in the template of directive B ?

Comment: Can't you just store it in your controller/scope?

Comment: Are A and B siblings or is A a parent of B ?

Comment: A and B are siblings, if they were parents it would be a different story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### first approach - dependency on the hosting controller's scope http://plnkr.co/edit/WuEN9hgfSoiIpR8ufocW?p=preview

**html**

```
<first-directive></first-directive>
<second-directive></second-directive>
```

**js**

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $location, $timeout) {

    $scope.items=['a ab', 'asd', 'www', '123'];
  }
);

app.directive('firstDirective', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: false,
      template: '<div><input ng-model="input"></div>'
    };
});


app.directive('secondDirective', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: false,
      template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:input">{{ item }}</div>'
    };
});
```

### Second approach - directive arguments http://plnkr.co/edit/zEJWgQfLgVzl2RpO3qhp?p=preview

**html**

```
<first-directive filter-string="filterString"></first-directive>
<second-directive filter-string="filterString" items="items"></second-directive>
```

**js**

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $location, $timeout) {
    $scope.items=['a ab', 'asd', 'www', '123'];
    $scope.filterString = '';
  }
);

app.directive('firstDirective', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: { filterString:"=" },
      template: '<div><input ng-model="filterString"></div>'
    };
});


app.directive('secondDirective', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: { filterString:"=",
      items:"="},
      template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterString">{{ item }}</div>'
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks for the fast and detailed answers =) much appreciated!

Comment: Do you by any chance happen to know why it stops working when I add an ng-if to it? http://plnkr.co/edit/vcnAf8bmRVKRyF00kbSE?p=preview

Comment: use `ng-show` instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/JLeY7aR6Md37bWoI0B0b?p=preview. why? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3225